# how to set value we get from controller in view

Tags: laravel, rest, controller, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I have a view in blade that need a certain data from an api, if i dd the value it will give me a correct value that i need, but if i try to echo the value, then it will popup this error
Undefined property: stdClass::$data

this is my code in blade view

```
@php
  $a = new stdClass();
  $a = $vehicleController::getDriverName($vehicle->driver_id)->data[0]->name;
  echo $a;
@endphp
```

this is the value if i dd($a) https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v7VM.png

this is the full data https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Kyu.png

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would want to use echo to display the data in a blade. You should avoid putting your application logic in the views. Instead, consider calling the *getDriverName* method before returning the view and then pass the data to the blade as described in the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#passing-data-to-components

When done correctly you can access the data in your blade like this:

```
<div>
    {{ $vehicle->data[0]->name }}
</div>
```

Comment: in my blade i have vehicles (i foreach the vehicles) that have driver_id, i need to show the name, so i called the getDriverName method that gives back a name from my API

Comment: Alright, then it's probably best to pass a collection of all vehicles with the corresponding driver data to the view and use Blade Loops to iterate through the data.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops